# Preloader wordpress minimum time

Tags: jquery, preloader

I need to create a preloader that stays for a minimum given time (6 seconds).
I don't know anything about jQuery, but this is the code of a Wordpress plugin and I guess I need to add the time here:

jQuery(function($){

```
var width = 100,
    perfData = window.performance.timing, // The PerformanceTiming interface represents timing-related performance information for the given page.
    EstimatedTime = -(perfData.loadEventEnd - perfData.navigationStart),
    time = parseInt((EstimatedTime/1000)%60)*100;

        var preloader = document.querySelector(".preloader-plus");
        $('body').prepend(preloader);

        var progBar = document.querySelector(".prog-bar"),
  start = 0,
  end = 70,
  duration = time,
        counter = document.getElementById("preloader-counter");

        animateValue(progBar, start, end, duration);

function animateValue(element, start, end, duration) {

var range = end - start,
    current = start,
    increment = end > start? 1 : -1,
    stepTime = Math.abs(Math.floor(duration / range)),
    obj = element;

var timer = setInterval(function() {
        if(current < end) {
            current += increment;
        }
        if (obj !== null) {
            obj.style["transition-duration"] = "0.001s";
            obj.style.width= current + "%";
        }
        if (counter !== null) {
    counter.innerHTML = current + "%";
        }
  if ( current == end ) {
            var endLoading = setInterval( function() {
                current += increment;
                if (obj !== null) {
                    obj.style.width= current + "%";
                }
                if (counter !== null) {
            counter.innerHTML = current + "%";
                }
                if(current == 100) {
                    setTimeout( function() {
                        $('body, .preloader-plus').addClass('complete');
                    }, preloader_plus.animation_delay)
                    clearInterval(endLoading);
                }
            }, 1)
            clearInterval(timer);
  }
}, stepTime);
}
```

});

If you could help I would very pleaseant, thanks! (If you need more information let me know)

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do you mean when you say "preload"?

Comment: A video that loads before the content is completely ready

Comment: Alright so you have a plan to load some video. Can you tell us what's wrong with the code above?

Comment: It's the code of the plugin I'm using. I just want to tell the script to load at least 6 seconds before load the page

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle?  Something like this?  https://jsfiddle.net/madmrshn/7e01jd0q/

Comment: actually I cannot do it.. is a wordpress plugin and it is mainly PHP. If you have wordpress you could see all the code of it with the download. I leave it here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ZB5bABim4xUSOPx6n-ObLcNv6a3YOeWK?usp=sharing